# How to resolve paypal subscription not working on live mode

Tags: paypal, subscription, live, mode

The Sandbox APIs are functioning properly; however, when we switch to the live mode with the live API, we are experiencing issues and it is not functioning as expected.

and we get an error like Failed to load resource:

```
the server responded with a status of 400 ()
```

Answer (score 0):

When changing to live mode, are you using live API credentials? Invalid credentials is the usual cause of a 400. (Sandbox credentials do not work in live, nor vice-versa; the two environments are completely separate.)

If using the current [Subscriptions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/), any plans created must also be for the live environment.

If this does not resolve your issue, the question needs more details, including example requests and response JSON bodies.

Comment: We check into the deep and find that, the token failed. 

check this screenshot link - https://ibb.co/VTXWzxw